# Sql list display duplicates

Tags: sql

I have a table with names and years.

```
Name    Year     
Adam    1960
Adam    1970
Adam    1980
Alex    1955
Alex    1956
Brian   1963
Cody    1959
....    ....
```

How can I list and display duplicates of names and years so that it shows 3 columns: name  and 2 "year" columns to produce a result like:

```
     Adam 1960 1970
     Adam 1960 1980
     Adam 1970 1980
     Alex 1955 1956
```

Adam has 3 results so it appears as 3 different rows:

However in the case of Alex(2 results) it only shows one row.

The non-duplicate names do now appear.

It also needs to be sorted by left-most year value, and then right-most year value

Also, is there a way to do this without using "GROUP BY"?

Thanks

Comment: which DBMS ?? what query you have tried ??

Answer (score 4):

Basically, just join the tables using `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT  a.Name, a.Year MinYear, b.Year MaxYEar
FROM    TableName a
        INNER JOIN TableName b
            ON a.Name = b.Name AND a.Year < b.Year
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53a634/2)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this solution:

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.age, t2.age FROM dbo.Table_1 AS t1
    CROSS APPLY dbo.Table_1 AS t2 
WHERE t1.name = t2.name
    AND t1.age < t2.age
```